# Visual Studio 2010 Errors When Switching Between Solutions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two solutions that I'm working on.  Both are WinForm based in VB.NET.  When I switch from the solution with 9 projects after making changes to the other with just one project I get a pop up telling me that VS 2010 is having trouble.  I've run devenv.exe as administrator and with /log option turned on to create the ActivityLog.XML file.  One entry shows up which appears to point to a VS extension but is not much help to me:

```
  <entry>
    <record>386</record>
    <time>2014/02/06 17:29:28.017</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.InvalidOperationException: Requesting a text view host when we 
      don&apos;t have one available.  Current state: Closed&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.get_WpfTextViewHost()
      &#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.HandleVerticalScroll()
      &#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.View_LayoutChanged(Object 
      sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, 
      EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)</description>
  </entry>
```

I thought I had a solution to this from the article  [Visual Studio 2010 Crashing on Solution Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238669/visual-studio-2010-crashing-on-solution-load). Unfortunately, I am not aware of any bogus code fragments that I created that could cause this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VS 2010 is known to crash. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054236/visual-studio-2010-crashes-after-pasting-simple-code). I had it crash 5-6 times today during 2-3 hours of development, all times while renaming a variable. How can they write code such that it crashes like that? Anyway, if you can, try to open your solution in VS 2013. Project/solution files are compatible, so there is no conversion involved. If no issues in VS 2013, chances are that it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately, VS 2013 is not an option at this time.